# How to limit max number of ElasticSearch documents in a index?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I've installed an Elastic Search (version 7.x) cluster and created a new index. I want to limit the maximum number of documents in this index. Let's say 10000 documents top.

The naive solution is to query the number of documents before inserting a new document into it. But this method can be not accurate and also have poor performances (2 requests...).

How to do it right?

Comment: curious to know why you want to restrict the max number of docs in your index?

Comment: The customer is paying per number of uploaded files... So I want to block the insert request after N documents...

Comment: got it , give me some time to and will get back to u

Comment: i undestand better your need, i updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to use [Index Life Management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/current/ilm.html#custom-ilm-policy) which is in the Basic License and enabled by default in Elastic v7.3+

You can set a [rollover action](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/creating-index-lifecycle-policies.html#setting-a-rollover-action) on the number of document (i put 5 max docs) :

```
PUT _ilm/policy/my_policy
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_docs": 5
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now i create a template with the policy `my_policy` :

```
PUT _template/my_template
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "my-index*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index.blocks.read_only" : true,
    "index.lifecycle.name": "my_policy",
    "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "my-index"
  }
}
```

Note that i put the setting `"index.blocks.read_only" : true` because when the rollover will be applied it will create a new index with read_only parameter.

Now i can create my index :

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "settings": {
    "index.blocks.read_only": false
  },
  "aliases": {
    "my-index": {
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

That's it ! After 5 documents, it will create a new read only index and the alias will be on writing on this one.

You can test by index some new docs with the alias :

```
PUT my-index/_doc/1
{
  "field" : "value"
}
```

Also, by default the ilm policy will be applied every 10 minutes, you can change that in order to test with :

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "indices.lifecycle.poll_interval": "5s"
  }
}
```

Comment: In a scenario where limit has reached and the index became read only, then i delete all documents from the original index. How to make the rollover in the oposite direction? How to make it go back to being read-only=false?

Comment: PUT my-index-000002/_settings
{
    "index.blocks.read_only": false
 }

Comment: This will make the index immediately writeable. I want that the threshold will be checked again by the policy and become writeable if the threshold isn't met. For example - if i put max 5 docs, and insert 5 docs in, making it read only. After that i delete 1 doc making index size 4. I want the policy to notice that, making an automatic rollover to becoming writeable